# How to emit signals with dbus-sharp?

Tags: c#, mono, dbus

Posted on the github issue tracker as well, https://github.com/mono/dbus-sharp/issues/43.

I have an interface with some methods that show up on dbus, I can call them with d-feet. I'd like to add some signals to my interface so the service can report when its status changes, connection is lost/restored etc, but I'm not sure how to do so.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

And I'll answer my own question:

- Add an event to your dbus object class, like:

  ```
  public class Blah : MarshalByRefObject
  {
      public event MyEventHandler OnEvent;

      public void EventHandler()
      {
          if(OnEvent != null) { OnEvent(); }
      }
  }
  ```
- Run 'dbus-monitor' to watch the dbus activity on your system
- Call Blah's EventHandler() method and see that the 'OnEvent' signal was sent from your dbus object.